# Bootstrap 5 collapse wont revert on second Button click

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-5

I have a Button which shows a div on Button Click using Boostrap 5 Class "Collapse". It actually shows the div on the first click, but the content wont hide again when the User clicks the Button a second time.

```
<div class="container">
   
    <button role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#rrCollapse" >Hinzufügen</button>
    <div class="collapse" id="rrCollapse">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">

                <h1>...</h1>
             
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Button and the div which collapses after a click

```
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

All files I used.

I am working on ASP.net Core 6.0

Comment: You've got way too many versions of the files included, you only need one of the bootstrap.css files, one of the jquery.js files and one of the bootstrap.js files. The `min` versions are just minified versions of the regular file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used the default  _Layout, and in the _Layout.cshtml there are the `<link>` and `<scrpit>` , you don't need to add these files to the view .

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

result:

[image]

**Update:**

In the view try below code:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}



<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   
    <button role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#rrCollapse" >Hinzufügen</button>
    <div class="collapse" id="rrCollapse">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">

                <h1>...</h1>
             
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my _Layout.cshtml, you can refer it to change your _layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - MVCForeignIT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/MVCForeignIT.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">MVCForeignIT</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2022 - MVCForeignIT - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didnt add these Files to the view. I added it to the Layout as you said. Now i reduced to Files to the amount you did use, and it unfortunately still didnt work.

Comment: @MAsports   Try to use `F12`  then console tab to see if any error message?

Comment: >This did actually work, but iam actually using the default Layout file, so I would not set the Layout null. Should i change something on  _Layout.cshtml?  There were no errors in the Console. Thank you tho!

Comment: @MAsports Please see my Layout.